# Authorize attribute v Authorizer.Authorize

Tags: orchardcms

In my Orchard module, I am considering replacing MVC's AuthorizeAttribute in my controller actions with a call to Authorizer.Authorize(). The advantage is that I can redirect back to the home page if a user is not authorized to access a page, thus not telling them it was an authentication issue.

Are there any security issues using this:

```
public ActionResult Edit( int id ) {
    if ( !_authorizer.Authorize( Permissions.MyPermission ) ) 
        return Redirect("~/");
    // do stuff here and return
}
```

instead of this:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit( int id ) {
    // do stuff here and return
}
```

Sanity checks are most appreciated.

Comment: The first allows you to take advantage of Orchard's permissions system, something not available in vanilla MVC, so I'd go with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With feedback from Hazza, the Authorizer.Authorize() version allows for the granularity of Orchard's permissions system. The [Authorize] attribute works great when the built-in ASP.NET roles system is sufficient.

I will likely use a combination of both depending upon what the controller action is doing. Thanks for your input Hazza!

Comment: I have performance issues and ask myself if is not because of that Authorize method inside the controller....